# How do I hold down a key in p5 instead of just pressing it repeatedly?

Tags: p5.js

This is the code that I am currently using but I've also tried while loops which crash the website.

```
function keyPressed() {
    if (keyCode == LEFT_ARROW) {
        stan.left();
      }
    else if (keyCode == RIGHT_ARROW) {
        stan.right();
      }
```

The stan.left and stan.right are just to move the character in the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the KeyIsDown() function.
This allows you to specify which key is needed to be pressed. There's another function called keyIsPressed() which will allow input from any key (within which you can set up an if statement along with a keyCode() function, which will allow only the specified key).

This site is the reference page for p5.js: https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/
Here you'll find every function along with examples that p5 offers.